# Codeigniter 3 - dynamic update status from dropdown

Tags: codeigniter

I've created dropdown with status ticket and now after submit I try update selected value:

```
<?php echo form_open('helpdesk_controller/update_status_post'); ?>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $ticket->id; ?>">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="fw-medium">Status:</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select class="form-select" id="t-status" data-choices data-choices-search-false aria-label="Default select example">
                                                            <option value>Stauts</option>
                                                            <option name="t-status" value="<?php echo html_escape($ticket->status); ?>" selected><?php echo html_escape($ticket->status); ?></option>
                                                            <option value="Open">Open</option>
                                                            <option value="Inprogress">Inprogress</option>
                                                            <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <button type="submit">Save</button>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                 <?php echo form_close(); ?><!-- form end -->
```

Please note:  I don't paste the model and controller code here because in this case they are unnecessary because they work properly.

[Dropdown preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3rRK.png)

```
    //input values
public function input_status_values()
{
    $data = array(
        'status' => $this->input->post('t-status', true)
    );
    return $data;
}
```

The problem is I post to database empty value.

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to set this dropdown to send the actually selected value from the dropdown to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The `name="t-status"` attribute should be on the select element, not on an option.

[A successful control must be defined within a FORM element and must have a control name.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)

Comment: I try also  <select class="form-select" name="t-status" id="t-status" data-choices data-choices-search-false aria-label="Default select example"> but still I post empty value.

Comment: Adding the name attribute to the form will send the value when submitting the form ([this can be checked in Chrome's developer tools](https://i.gyazo.com/9e64fc7c80b5ff2d26758017f93b23a0.png)). If you don't see this, then maybe some javascript is at work preventing the default event and sending an AJAX request instead?

As soon as the data is sent by the browser, the next point to check would be Helpdesk_controller, method update_status_post() when you try to get this value? Are any input_filters making it empty? Does $this->input->post('t-status', true) itself not have data?